# Share variables between Swift and Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I created a global URL variable in Swift and now I want to pass it to a class written in Objective-C using `override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?`, but `value of type AudioView has no member 'urlToPlay'. Here's what I've done:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "AudioView" {
        let vc = segue.destination as! AudioView
        vc.urlToPlay = songPlayURL // error
    } 
}

@interface AudioView ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSURL *urlToPlay;

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by adding the `@property` in the header file. :)